# What is the effect of a non-existent economy on the environment of a world

Tags: environment, economy

I would like some ideas on how the environment of a world where an economy (nothing financial and no currency system) did not exist - would be affected, would progress etc etc.

Comment: You will probably need to specify more detail to avoid close votes. Hopefully lots of people will comment with the extra detail that is needed so that you can clarify your question with answers to their questions.

Comment: Do you mean a barter system (which is a type of economy but without currency) or no economy at all?

Comment: Do you mean that ownership is never exchanged? Or that there is no ownership and people help themselves to whatever they want?

Comment: When you ask about "the environment" do you mean climate and ecosystems and how living things are affected, or the wider meaning of how the surroundings in general are affected?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about a human world? Earth had no economy prior to the arrival of humans. It's worth being specific one way or another.

Comment: "Economy" and "finance" are two distinct things. Money can be part of an economy, but it is not at all necessary.  Rather than saying what's not present, it would be better to describe what *is*.  Otherwise the question is just way to broad.

Comment: This question is still a little unclear (putting society instead of world might be better), and definitely too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the question is why would a people not trade.

A. They don't need to, they are altruistic and live in a pseudo utopia

B. They don't care to/don't see the point Fatalisitic what comes, comes

C. Have no sense of ownership.  Everything is everyone's for the using/consuming, like a hive

Comment: D. The people of the world are very territorial and don't accept strangers at all, so there is nobody outside the established group to trade with.

Comment: E. There are no people.